# Synchronized Transactional method in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, synchronization, synchronized

We have following method in our code which has `Transactional` annotation and is synchronized.

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public synchronized void addValueToDB(String value, int parent) {
  int nextId = getNextIDUsingSequence();
  insertIntoDB(nextId, value);
  updateLeft(parent);
  updateRight(parent);
}
```

Now as `Transactional` annotation commits in database after method completion so **synchronization** on this method seems useless to me? Does spring provides any solution to this or should I synchronize the block from where this method is getting called?

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Can you share your solution? Thanks.

Comment: @PedroPedruzzi What we did is, we synchronized the block in service layer from where this method was getting called.

Answer (score 2):

transactions and synchronization are two different things:

1. a TX (transaction) means your code **will not see** the effects of other TXs running alongsde it (up to a point...), but wont prevent other TX from running. for example you could try and alter the same database row from 2 TXs. one (the 1st to commit) will succeed and the other would fail.
2. synchronization prevents multiple thread from executing your method (on the same instance of your class. is your class a singleton?) at the same time. it offers much more powerful isolation

you need to decide which of the 2 you need

Comment: these are 2 different things but we need both. So the question is where should be the synchronization? (or does spring provides any solution?)

Answer (score 0):

instead of that make "getNextIdUSingSequnence" method syncronized. Transactional annotaion will take care of the method addValueToDb.